# WebRTC iOS: Audio/Video stream recording

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am trying to record `incoming/outgoing` `audio/video` streams in my `iOS` app that uses `GoogleWebRTC` pod. so far I haven't found any api that allows us to record `Audio/Video` streams. I tried to record local video feed from the camera using `AVCaptureSession`, but doing this freezes the outgoing video stream. this happens probably because multiple `AVCaptureSession` instances cannot use the same input device.

Is there any other way to record local and/or remote streams from `WebRTC` in `iOS`?

Comment: Are you using any platform like TokBox to power your WebRTC sessions? They can route the streams through a (TURN) server where they are recorded locally.

Comment: no, i'm using this pod https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC

Comment: Hi @Rezwan not sure if this is still actual, but you can use Apples ReplayKit to capture/record audio and/or video streams.

Answer (score 1):

Replay kit, but that has limitations.

The alternative method is using the actual lib, no the cocoa pods, and extract audio/video from each incoming stream.

Once you have the actual video/audio currently being displayed/played you can combine and mux as you see fit.

Very complex though